# action is not dispatch to store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have dispatch actions, but can't see any action type in my reducer.

Here is my action:

```
export const SET_SEARCH_BRAND_TYPE = 'SET_SEARCH_BRAND_TYPE';

export const setSearchBrandType = value => ({
  type: SET_SEARCH_BRAND_TYPE,
  value,
});
```

The reducer :

```
import {
  SET_SEARCH_BRAND_TYPE,
} from '../actions/searchAction';

const initialState = {
  searchBrandType: '',
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  console.log('test');
  console.log(action.type); // here i can't get my action type
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_SEARCH_BRAND_TYPE:
      return { ...state, searchBrandType: action.value };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

My container:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as searchActions from '../../actions/searchAction';
import DropDownButton from '../dropDownButton';
import './style.css';

class SearchBar extends Component {
  state = {
    brandValues: [],
    vehicleTypes: [],
    areas: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.prepareData();
  }

  prepareData() {
    this.setState({
      brandValues: ['BMW', 'Audi', 'M BENZ'],
      vehicleTypes: ['四門房車', '休旅車', '敞篷車', '性能跑車'],
      areas: ['台北', '台中', '台南'],
    });
  }

  handleSelectOption(selectType, selectedOption) {
    if (selectType === 'brand') {
      console.log(selectedOption);
      searchActions.setSearchBrandType(selectedOption);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="searchBar">
        <div>
          <span>我要預約體驗</span>
        </div>
        <DropDownButton
          selectType="brand"
          name="廠牌"
          options={this.state.brandValues}
          handleSelectOption={this.handleSelectOption}
        />
        <DropDownButton
          selectType="vehicleTypes"
          name="車型"
          options={this.state.vehicleTypes}
          handleSelectOption={this.handleSelectOption}
        />
        <DropDownButton
          selectType="areas"
          name="地區"
          options={this.state.areas}
          handleSelectOption={this.handleSelectOption}
        />
        <div>
          <span onClick={()=> this.submitSearch()}>搜尋</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  searchBrandType: state.search.searchBrandType,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  searchActions: bindActionCreators(searchActions, dispatch),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchBar);
```

and here is the store:

```
import { combineReducers, createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { routerMiddleware, routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import searchReducer from './reducers/searchReducer';

export const history = createHistory();

const initialState = {};
const enhancers = [];
const middleware = [
  thunk,
  routerMiddleware(history),
];
const reducer = combineReducers({
  route: routerReducer,
  search: searchReducer,
});

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  const devToolsExtension = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__;

  if (typeof devToolsExtension === 'function') {
    enhancers.push(devToolsExtension());
  }
}

const composedEnhancers = compose(
  applyMiddleware(...middleware),
  ...enhancers,
);

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composedEnhancers,
);

export default store;
```

I already tried for the whole day, I did dispatch in my container, but still can not get my action.type in the reducer. and the redux chrome extension doesn't show any my action.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Is your react component tree correctly wrapped into the `<Provider>` component that knows the store?

Comment: `searchActions.setSearchBrandType(selectedOption);` this should be `this.props.searchActions.setSearchBrandType(selectedOption);`. You're calling the unbound action creator, so you're just creating the action, not dispatching it.

Comment: @trixn Yes, I did wrap with   `<Provider store={store}>`

Comment: @NicholasTower I tired it but shows `Cannot read property 'searchActions' of undefined`

Comment: It should be `this.props.searchActions`

Comment: @NicholasTower I know why! Cuz i can't write `this.props` in the function!! THX a lot !!!

Comment: @dealwap THX~!!! I got it!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should **replace your code from:**

    `searchActions.setSearchBrandType(selectedOption);`

**to:**

    `this.props.searchActions.setSearchBrandType(selectedOption)`

*P.S. Previous you tried to call action without dispatching.*